# numpy.genfromtxt- ValueError- Line # (got n columns instead of m)

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

So, I've been writing up code to read in a dataset from a file and separate it out for analysis.

The data in question is read from a .dat file, and looks like this:

```
14        HO2       O3        OH        O2        O2
15        HO2       HO2       H2O2      O2
16        H2O2      OH        HO2       H2O
17        O         O         O2
18        O         O2        O3
19        O         O3        O2        O2
```

The code I've written looks like this:

```
edge_data=np.genfromtxt('Early_earth_reaction.dat', dtype = str, 
missing_values=True, filling_values=bool)
```

The plan was that I'd then run the values from the dataset and build a paired list from them.

```
edge_list=[]
for i in range(360):
    edge_list.append((edge_data[i,0],edge_data[i,2]))
    edge_list.append((edge_data[i,1],edge_data[i,2]))
    print edge_data[i,0]
    if edge_data[i,3] != None:
        edge_list.append((edge_data[i,0],edge_data[i,3]))
        edge_list.append((edge_data[i,1],edge_data[i,3]))
    if edge_data[i,4]!= None:
        edge_list.append((edge_data[i,0],edge_data[i,4]))
        edge_list.append((edge_data[i,1,edge_data[i,4]))
```

However, upon running it, I get the error message

```
File "read_early_earth.py", line 52, in main
edge_data=np.genfromtxt('Early_earth_reaction.dat', dtype = str,  
usecols=(1,2,3,4,5), missing_values=True, filling_values=bool)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1667, 
in genfromtxt
raise ValueError(errmsg)
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
Line #6 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
Line #14 (got 6 columns instead of 5)
Line #17 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
```

And so on and so forth. As far as I can tell, this is happening because there are rows where not all the columns have values in them, which apparently throws numpy for a loop.

Is there a work-around for this in numpy?  Alternatively, is there another way to accomplish this task?  I know, worse comes to worse, I can torture some regular expressions into doing the job, but I'd prefer a method that's a bit more efficient if at all possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've already read `genfromtxt` about missing values.  Does it say anything about the use of delimiters?

I think it can handle missing values with lines like

```
'one, 1, 234.4, , ,'
'two, 3, , 4, 5'
```

but when the delimiter is the default 'white-space' it can't.  One of the first steps after reading a line is

```
 strings = line.split(delimiter)
```

And objects if `len(strings)` doesn't match with the initial target.  Apparently it does not try to guess that you want to pad the line with `n-len(strings)` missing values.

Options that come to mind:

- try Pandas; it may make more effort to guess your intentions
- write your own reader.  Pandas is compiled; `genfromtxt` is plain numpy Python.  It reads the file line by line, splits and converts fields, and appends the list to a master list.  It converts that list of lists into array at the end.  Your own reader should be just as efficient.
- preprocess your file to add the missing values or change the delimiter.  `genfromtxt` accepts anything that feeds it lines.  So it works with a list of strings, a file reader that yields modified lines, etc.  This may be simplest.

  def foo(astr):
      strs=astr.split()
      if len(strs)<6:
          strs.extend([b' ']*(6-len(strs)))
      return b','.join(strs)

Simulating with a list of strings (in Py3):

```
In [139]: txt=b"""14        HO2       O3        OH        O2        O2
     ...: 15        HO2       HO2       H2O2      O2
     ...: 16        H2O2      OH        HO2       H2O
     ...: 17        O         O         O2
     ...: 18        O         O2        O3
     ...: 19        O         O3        O2        O2""".splitlines()

In [140]: [foo(l) for l in txt]
Out[140]: 
[b'14,HO2,O3,OH,O2,O2',
 b'15,HO2,HO2,H2O2,O2, ',
 b'16,H2O2,OH,HO2,H2O, ',
 b'17,O,O,O2, , ',
 b'18,O,O2,O3, , ',
 b'19,O,O3,O2,O2, ']

In [141]: np.genfromtxt([foo(l) for l in txt], dtype=None, delimiter=',')
Out[141]: 
array([(14, b'HO2', b'O3', b'OH', b'O2', b'O2'),
       (15, b'HO2', b'HO2', b'H2O2', b'O2', b''),
       (16, b'H2O2', b'OH', b'HO2', b'H2O', b''),
       (17, b'O', b'O', b'O2', b' ', b''),
       (18, b'O', b'O2', b'O3', b' ', b''),
       (19, b'O', b'O3', b'O2', b'O2', b'')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', 'S4'), ('f2', 'S3'), ('f3', 'S4'), ('f4', 'S3'), ('f5', 'S2')])
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data is nicely aligned in fields of exactly 10 characters.  If that is always the case, you can tell `genfromtxt` the field widths to use by specifying the sequence of field widths in the `delimiter` argument.

Here's an example.

First, your data file:

```
In [20]: !cat reaction.dat
14        HO2       O3        OH        O2        O2
15        HO2       HO2       H2O2      O2
16        H2O2      OH        HO2       H2O
17        O         O         O2
18        O         O2        O3
19        O         O3        O2        O2
```

For convenience, I'll define the number of fields and the field width here. (In general, it is not necessary that all the fields have the same width.)

```
In [21]: numfields = 6

In [22]: fieldwidth = 10
```

Tell `genfromtxt` that the data is in fixed width columns by passing in the argument `delimiter=(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)`:

```
In [23]: data = genfromtxt('reaction.dat', dtype='S%d' % fieldwidth, delimiter=(fieldwidth,)*numfields)
```

Here's the result.  Note that "missing" fields are empty strings.  Also note that non-empty fields include the white space, and the last non-empty field in each row includes the newline character:

```
In [24]: data
Out[24]: 
array([[b'14        ', b'HO2       ', b'O3        ', b'OH        ',
        b'O2        ', b'O2\n'],
       [b'15        ', b'HO2       ', b'HO2       ', b'H2O2      ',
        b'O2\n', b''],
       [b'16        ', b'H2O2      ', b'OH        ', b'HO2       ',
        b'H2O\n', b''],
       [b'17        ', b'O         ', b'O         ', b'O2\n', b'', b''],
       [b'18        ', b'O         ', b'O2        ', b'O3\n', b'', b''],
       [b'19        ', b'O         ', b'O3        ', b'O2        ',
        b'O2\n', b'']], 
      dtype='|S10')

In [25]: data[1]
Out[25]: 
array([b'15        ', b'HO2       ', b'HO2       ', b'H2O2      ', b'O2\n',
       b''], 
      dtype='|S10')
```

We could clean up the strings in a second step, or we can have `genfromtxt` do it by providing a converter for each field that simply strips the white space from the field:

```
In [26]: data = genfromtxt('reaction.dat', dtype='S%d' % fieldwidth, delimiter=(fieldwidth,)*numfields, converters={k: lambda s: s.
    ...: strip() for k in range(numfields)})

In [27]: data
Out[27]: 
array([[b'14', b'HO2', b'O3', b'OH', b'O2', b'O2'],
       [b'15', b'HO2', b'HO2', b'H2O2', b'O2', b''],
       [b'16', b'H2O2', b'OH', b'HO2', b'H2O', b''],
       [b'17', b'O', b'O', b'O2', b'', b''],
       [b'18', b'O', b'O2', b'O3', b'', b''],
       [b'19', b'O', b'O3', b'O2', b'O2', b'']], 
      dtype='|S10')

In [28]: data[:,0]
Out[28]: 
array([b'14', b'15', b'16', b'17', b'18', b'19'], 
      dtype='|S10')

In [29]: data[:,5]
Out[29]: 
array([b'O2', b'', b'', b'', b'', b''], 
      dtype='|S10')
```